# Jquery: Select all H2 tags on page, copy the text of those H2 tags to a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, foreach, each

Is there a very simple way to select all H2 tags on the page, then take the text in those H2 tags and add the text of each one to a list.

example:

```
<H2>I'm number one!</H2>
<H2>I'm number two?</H2>
<H2>I'm number three.</H2>
```

the script will grab those, and copy their contents into a list when the page is loaded:

```
<UL>
<LI>I'm number one!</LI>
<LI>I'm number two?</LI>
<LI>I'm number three.</LI>
</UL>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:

```
$('h2').each(function() {
  $('ul').append($('<li/>', {text: $(this).text()});
});
```

Of course you might want to tag your `<ul>` element with an "id" or whatever. If you don't start off with a `<ul>` on the page, then you'd construct it as described in a couple other answers.

Also, as Nick correctly points out, if there are a bunch of those `<h2>` elements then you might want to stash the jQuery handle for the `<ul>` element in a variable, to save the repeated lookup.

Comment: Yes Nick I would too :-)  It's hard to type in a really polished answer fast enough around here!

Comment: Damn it!  you guys are too fast.  Was posting my answer when you already answered it :(

Comment: Ha ha I actually switched to using Chrome recently because I was getting so sick of Firefox getting really laggy in the "Answer" editor  :-)

Comment: It's better to use `'<li>' + foo + '</li>'` instead of your way. See this url: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly.

Comment: Yes @Guido that's a good point - again, if there are a whole bunch of `<h2>` elements it could be sluggish, so you'd want to build up the `<ul>` contents as a string and append the DOM chunk all at once.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery it's really easy:

```
var ul = $('<ul />');
$('h2').each(function(obj) {
    ul.append('<li>' + $(obj).html() + '</li>');
});
```

Now `ul` will contain the `h2`-titles. :)